macでフィンガープリントを取得しようとするとkeytoolエラー: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore formatと出る
経緯
作成しているflutterアプリからfirebaseを使用しようと思い、フィンガープリントが必要になったので取得しようとしたところ、上記のエラーが表示されました。
環境
M3 Macbook
やったこと
コマンド実行
下記のコマンドを実行
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

下記のエラーが出力された
keytoolエラー: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:666)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:71)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:832)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:375)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:368)

引用
MacOS+M2でAndroid用SHA-1のフィガープリントを表示する方法
Android Studioから取得しようとした
参考
Android Studioで簡単なSHA-1発給。 - Qiita
「Gradle -> app -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport」 から取得できるようだが、そもそもGradleが見つからなかった


直接の回答ではありませんが、参考にしている Qiita のページを追体験できるように Gradle のインストールをなさってはどうでしょう。Gradle のインストールは SDKMAN! を利用するのが便利です。
Gradle のインストールができていれば Android Studio の画面は次の様になります。

